# What to do with Laravel pagitation problem?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, request

The next problem

```
$quotes=Quote::wherein('id', [12,13,14,15,16])->paginate(3);
return view ('quotes_by_categories', ['quotes'=>$quotes]);
```

here's everything works
but

```
      $quotes = Quote::whereHas('themes', function($q)
        {
          $q->wherein('thema', ['txt1', 'txt2', 'txt3']);
        })->paginate(3);
return view ('quotes_by_categories', ['quotes'=>$quotes]);
```

-- blank page in view.
When i make dump - the result of first and second request is the same, everything is ok. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return view('quotes_by_categories',compact('quotes'))
```

Comment: I don't know what does it mean and how it works but it works! Thak you!!

Comment: For completeness, you should always explain your answer